# html jquery.load, dynamic file names

Tags: jquery, html

i got a menu made with li / a, and i got jquery.load working with this. when i click on a link it loads without refreshing the page the content in a div. but what is the best way to add the filename that has to be loaded in an attribute?

this will load the page with the original link: 127.0.0.1/filetobeloaded.html for example.
`<a href="filetobeloaded.html">test</a>`

but if i do `<a href="#" rel="filetobeloaded.html">test</a>` i think this is the wrong attribute =/.

so what attribute should i use for this?

Greets,
Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `href` attribute, that's what it is for. In the `.click` function you just do a `return false`. That will prevent the browser from redirecting to that page.

```
<a href="filetoload.html" class="ajaxLinks">MyLink</a>

$('.ajaxLinks').click(function() {
    // do something with this.href       

    return false;
});
```

Using the `href` attribute gives you the option to let it work without javascript.

Comment: an explanation on the downvote would be nice. we're all here to learn something ;).

Answer (score 1):

Use href attribute. So that it will work for your javascript disabled browsers too.

```
<a href="yourpage.html" class="ajaxLink">Link 1</a>
```

and in Script

```
$(function(){

 $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault() //to prevent the normal behaviour of a tag
    $("#yourContentdiv").load($(this).attr("href"));
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  it is fine to use href or rel, in another element you would use data- like data-load="url"

on a click you just need to supress the event, so:

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
  // load stuff here using $(this).attr('href')
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```